# Problems installing xfun (for rmarkdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, install.packages

I'm writing a tutorial for Rstudio for students that are complete novices with R. To run the tutorial using learnr, students need to have learnr and rmarkdown installed. But I'm running into a problem with xfun, which is one of the dependencies for rmarkdown. Installing xfun gives me an old version (0.22), but a later version (>=0.23) is needed to install tinytex and rmarkdown. I've tried this now on a couple of Windows computers with the latest version of R and had the same issue.

Workaround: On my own computer, I downloaded the .zip file for the source code for xfun and manually installed it in RStudio by going to Tools -> Install Packages... However, that seems too complicated to guide students through before they can even start the basic tutorial.

Does anyone know of a way to easily (with a line or two of code) force R to install the most recent version of xfun? I'd like to be able to give my students commands to copy into R so that they can install the necessary packages and run rmarkdown/ learnr tutorials.

Here is the output I'm getting when I try to install learnr:

```
> install.packages("learnr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kyrad/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘rmarkdown’


  There are binary versions available but the
  source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
tinytex     0.31   0.34             FALSE
xfun        0.22   0.26              TRUE
rmarkdown    2.8   2.11             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/xfun_0.22.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 323923 bytes (316 KB)
downloaded 316 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/learnr_0.10.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1661500 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘learnr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\kyrad\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmwhs1M\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘tinytex’, ‘rmarkdown’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.34.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 30196 bytes (29 KB)
downloaded 29 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3212367 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.22 is being loaded, but >= 0.23 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/kyrad/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tinytex'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tinytex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'tinytex' is not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/kyrad/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\kyrad\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpmwhs1M\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Did you try ```update.packages("xfun")```?

Comment: `Install.packages(“xfun”, dependencies=TRUE)` might do the trick, replace “xfun” with whatever package needs installed  ,you can have them download an older version of R/Rstudio if this is a major version issue, also updating R could work too